# LDA or pLSA for short documents?

Tags: topic-models, dirichlet-process, latent-semantic-analysis, latent-semantic-indexing

I'd like to classify short documents, from a **predefined set of words**.

What algorithm would you suggest, LDA or pLSA ?

### My use case

I have a list of users, and for each user a list of the pages she likes.

My goal is to classify users (documents) into classes (topics).

The documents are short, since a user is not likely to to like more than dozens of pages, and there are approximately 100k pages I care about

Comment: Could you give some more detail, like what is your goal? For what use is the classification? Is the classes also predefined, making it a classification problem, or undefined/unknown, making it into a clustering problem? Without some more information this cannot be answered.

Comment: added some more data on my use case

Comment: Topic modeling for short documents is discussed here: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/25558/topic-models-for-short-documents